# Is there any way to upload a file to Microsoft QnA Maker KB from visual studio?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to change the knowledge base of my QnA maker service in Microsoft QnA maker site. Is it possible to upload a file to this service from my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can update your KB by using the [QnAMaker v2.0 APIs](https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/ApiReference).

In particular, you can use the [Update Knowledge Base](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a083d9e041ad42d9bad) operation, which will allow you to add/delete QnA Pairs and / or URLs to an existing knowledge base.

Answer (score 0):

There's no possibility to add a KB through code. You can upload the KB as a file to QnA service. The KB file should be in .tsv, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xlsx formats.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can create KBs via code with the V2.0 APIs (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa)